# Binstar is creating problems with any conda commands

Tags: anaconda, conda, binstar

I'm using Anaconda 2.3.0 in Linux to manage packages in Python 2 and 3.  Recently, I've run into a problem when I try to execute:

```
conda update conda
```

I get an error as follows:

```
Error:  Could not find Binstar user ~
```

My conda info is as follows:

Current conda install:

```
         platform : linux-32
    conda version : 3.14.1
conda-build version : 1.14.1
   python version : 3.4.3.final.0
 requests version : 2.7.0
 root environment : /home/mbadros/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /home/mbadros/anaconda3
 envs directories : /home/mbadros/anaconda3/envs
    package cache : /home/mbadros/anaconda3/pkgs
     channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-32/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-32/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                    https://conda.anaconda.org/~/envs/linux-32/
                    https://conda.anaconda.org/~/envs/noarch/
      config file : /home/mbadros/.condarc
is foreign system : False
```

I have edited the .condarc file so that it contains only the - defaults channel.  Somehow, this Binstar user '~' crept into my Anaconda and I can't eliminate it.  Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the URL `https://conda.anaconda.org/~/envs/linux-32/` throws a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Is that an error that I should fix by removing this url from the channels?  If so, how?  Or is it a temporary issue at conda.anaconda.org?  Grateful for your input.

Comment: When I get home I'll do a fresh conda install and see what my channels list looks like. You can try commenting them out to see what happens.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help.  Right now, as I mentioned originally, I have edited the .condarc file so that it contains only the "- defaults" channel.  So these are the default URLs that are identified or pulled from somewhere else.

Comment: Problem is solved - I needed to remove (i.e., comment out) environment locations in my .condarc file, including a line that read:
`- ~/envs`.  Thanks to @Samuel-OMalley for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @MarkBadros you should add an answer so that anyone with the same problem in the future will find it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to remove (i.e., comment out) the environment locations in the .condarc file.  There was a line that read
`- ~/envs`
which should be commented out.